Jenkins pipeline: need to get string parameter scriptpath from 'Pipeline with SCM' UI settings
Need to get string parameter 'scriptpath' (path to exact groovy file) from 'Pipeline with SCM' UI settings - from the inside of pipe during its processing.
Without using:
currentBuild.rawBuild.* jenkins.internal.* (both are blocked), or
parsing config xml file for the whole job with auth request, it's too complicated for this task.
Do we have any other methods besides manually adding another one custom string parameter for each job just with path to groovy file?
Description is above

Can't think of any other way to get this info, but what do you need it for?

We need the exact Groovy file name for each job for further management - adding it to descriptions automatically, etc.

It sounds like you are the admin, so setting up a shared library should be easy enough, and currentBuild.rawBuild is not blocked there. If you are not the admin then adding the file name into every file as a static final variable seems like the easiest way forward.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
